# Dar formato a fecha AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estoy sacando de un API varios datos de una persona y necesito dar formato a una fecha.

Al hacer la llamada al API para sacar la fecha

```
vm.preconcedido.datosPersona.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento
```

Me aparece la fecha tal que así *1961-05-29T00:00:00.000+0100*

He intentado dar el formato con el

```
.format(DD/mm/AAAA);
```

y no me formatea correctamente la fecha.

¿Cómo podría dar el formato correcto a dicha fecha?

Muchas gracias, un saludo

Comment: estas usando algún framework ? o solo el new Date() comun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De forma nativa `AngularJS` tiene el filtro **[date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)**, en el que sólo debes específicar el formato deseado. Ahora bien, si sólo quieres utilizar la forma nativa de `Javascript` deberás obtener **[día](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getDate)**, **[mes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getMonth)** *(a este se le debe sumar 1, ya que Enero cuenta como el mes 0)* y **[año](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getFullYear)** por separado y concatenarlos en una variable; y por último si usas **[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)** sólo específicas el formato con la función `format('formatoDeseado')`.

Te dejo los ejemplos

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.fecha1 = new Date();
  $scope.fecha2 = new Date().getDate() + '-' + (new Date().getMonth() + 1) + '-' + new Date().getFullYear();
  $scope.fecha3 = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
}])
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label class="control-label text-success">Forma nativa AngularJS -> {{fecha1 | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</label>
  <br>
  <label class="control-label text-danger">Forma nativa Javascript -> {{fecha2}}</label>
  <br>
  <label class="control-label text-info">Forma momentJS -> {{fecha3}}</label>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok gracias, viendo el código que me has puesto, me di cuenta que estaba poniendo el formato de fecha **.format()** pero no el **moment()** y poniendo `moment(ruta de llamada al API para mostrar la fecha).format(MMMM, YYYY)` ya me apareció la fecha correctamente formateada. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una forma mas rapida de convertir es utilizar de manera nativa las funciones de JavaScript ;

```
$scope.miFecha = new Date($scope.miFecha).toString()
$scope.miFecha = new Date($scope.miFecha).toString()
$scope.miFecha = new Date($scope.miFecha).toLocaleString()
$scope.miFecha = new Date($scope.miFecha).toLocaleDateString()
$scope.miFecha = new Date($scope.miFecha).toLocaleTimeString()
```

O directamente con el binding {{}},
podrias hacer lo siguientes :

```
<div>
{{miFecha |date}}
{{miFecha |date : "dd.MM.y"}}
{{miFecha |date : "dd/MM/y" }}
{{miFecha |date : "dd-MM-y"}}
</div>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo :
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FV2M84LNHNYJ

Tambien en tu modulo principal puedes colocar la siguiente configuracion
:

```
  $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
            return date ? moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '';
        };

        $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function(dateString) {
            var m = moment(dateString, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);
            return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
        };
```